# Program to generate a matrix defined by user in java

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

guys!

First of all, I'm from Brazil, so sorry if I make some grammar error.

I'm having problems to solve an exercise in whitch I have to a program that generates a matix in java with user-informed dimensions. Then, it has to fill the matrix with values ​​which are also entered by the user. My code stops of running in my second for, passing by the columns. I get a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException. Can you help me to see what I'm doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DiagonalsSum {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int[][] matrix;
int[] sizes = new int[2];
int diagonalsSum = 0, i, j, n, m;
for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    n = i + 1;
    System.out.println("Inform the " + n + " dimension of the matrix");
    sizes[i] = s.nextInt();
}
matrix = new int[sizes[0]][sizes[1]];

for(i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++){
    n = i + 1;
    System.out.println(n);
    for(j = 0; j < matrix[sizes[0]].length; j++){
        m = j = 1;
        System.out.println("Inform the value of " + n + "." + m +
                " in the matrix:");
        matrix[i][j] = s.nextInt();
    }
}
s.close();
i = 0;
j = 0;
while(i < matrix.length && j < matrix[sizes[1]].length){
    diagonalsSum += matrix[i][j];
    i++;
    j++;
}
i = 0;
j = (matrix[sizes[i]].length - 1);
while(i < matrix.length && j > 0){
    diagonalsSum += matrix[i][j];
    i++;
    j--;
}
System.out.println("The sum of the primary and secondary diagonals is " + diagonalsSum);
}
```

Thanks in advance, guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guys!

I changed some things and it worked!

Thanks for all the help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DiagonalsSum {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int[][] matrix;
int[] sizes = new int[2];
int diagonalsSum = 0, i, j, n, m;
for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    n = i + 1;
    System.out.println("Inform the " + n + " dimension of the matrix");
    sizes[i] = s.nextInt();
}
matrix = new int[sizes[0]][sizes[1]];

for(i = 0; i < sizes[0]; i++){
    n = i + 1;
    System.out.println(n);
    for(j = 0; j < sizes[1]; j++){
        m = j = 1;
        System.out.println("Inform the value of " + n + "." + m +
                " in the matrix:");
        matrix[i][j] = s.nextInt();
    }
}
s.close();
i = 0;
j = 0;
while(i < sizes[0] && j sizes[1]){
    diagonalsSum += matrix[i][j];
    i++;
    j++;
}
i = 0;
j = (sizes[1] - 1);
while(i < sizes[0] && j > -1){
    diagonalsSum += matrix[i][j];
    i++;
    j--;
}
System.out.println("The sum of the primary and secondary diagonals is " + diagonalsSum);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for(i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++){
    matrix[i] = new int[sizes[1]];
    n = i + 1;
    System.out.println(n);
    for(j = 0; j < matrix[sizes[0]].length; j++){
        m = j = 1;
        System.out.println("Inform the value of " + n + "." + m +
                " in the matrix:");
        matrix[i][j] = s.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Java's an object-oriented language.  You'll do better if you encapsulate the behavior you need in a proper `Matrix` class.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a couple of errors in here, but I'll address the one you've asked about.

I believe

```
for(j = 0; j < matrix[sizes[0]].length; j++)
```

will always result in going out of bounds because you've declared:

```
matrix = new int[sizes[0]][sizes[1]];
```

Note that Java has 0 based indexing, meaning that for any array, `array[array.length]` will be out of bounds. This type of access is effectively what your for loop is doing.

```
for(j = 0; j < matrix[sizes[0]-1].length; j++)
```

should fix the column loop issue.